# compare Two array and result only the values

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to filter an array of objects

```
const arrayOne = [
    {id: 33, name: "fruit"},
    {id: 157, name: "car"},
    {id: 193, name: "water"},
];

const arrayTwo = [33, 193];
```

I need only the names in an array (without the key)

Expected output

```
["fruit", "water"]
```

Comment: `arrayTwo.map(item => arrayOne.find(({ id }) => id === item).name);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** You can easily achive the result using [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

```js
const arrayOne = [
  { id: 33, name: "fruit" },
  { id: 157, name: "car" },
  { id: 193, name: "water" },
];
const map = new Map();
arrayOne.forEach((o) => map.set(o.id, o.name));

const arrayTwo = [33, 193];
const result = arrayTwo.map((o) => map.get(o));

console.log(result);
```

**2)** You can also achieve the result using [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

```js
const arrayOne = [
  { id: 33, name: "fruit" },
  { id: 157, name: "car" },
  { id: 193, name: "water" },
];

const arrayTwo = [33, 193];
const result = arrayTwo.map((id) => arrayOne.find((o) => o.id === id)?.name);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can just simply do

```js
const arrayOne = [
  { id: 33, name: "fruit" },
  { id: 157, name: "car" },
  { id: 193, name: "water" }
];

const arrayTwo = [33, 193];
let keepResult = [];
arrayOne.map((a1) => {
  arrayTwo.map((a2) => {
    if (a1.id === a2) {
      keepResult.push(a1.name);
    }
  });
});

console.log("result show", keepResult);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const arrayOne = [
    {id: 33, name: "fruit"},
    {id: 157, name: "car"},
    {id: 193, name: "water"},
];

const arrayTwo = [33, 193];

let newArray = arrayOne.filter(item => arrayTwo.includes(item.id)).map(item => item.name)

console.log(newArray);
```

try this

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

this function is your solution:

```
const findNames = () => {
let names = []
arrayOne.forEach(item => {
    if (arrayTwo.includes(item.id)) {
        names = [...names, item.name]
     }
   })
  return names
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your **compare()** function for getting array of names based on two array

```
const arrayOne = [
    {id: 33, name: "fruit"},
    {id: 157, name: "car"},
    {id: 193, name: "water"},
];

const arrayTwo = [33, 157];

function compare(arrayOne, arrayTwo) {
    let result = [];
    arrayOne.filter(element => arrayTwo.indexOf(element.id) !== -1 ).forEach(element => { result.push(element.name) });
    return result ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a flatmap on the first array and include only those members having an `id` property included in array two.

```
arrayOne.flatMap(({ id, name }) => arrayTwo.includes(id) ? [name]: []);
```

```js
const arrayOne = [
  {id: 33, name: "fruit"},
  {id: 157, name: "car"},
  {id: 193, name: "water"},
];

const arrayTwo = [33, 193];

const result = arrayOne.flatMap(({ id, name }) => arrayTwo.includes(id) ? [name]: []);

console.log(result);
```